# How to disable right click on htmlpage using silverlight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I have recently started doing the coding in Silverlight application.I am not having great ideas about it. Now I am having the problem while disable right click Silverlight applications in a HTML page. I have tried to do lot of things but was not succeeded.Please help me **how to disable right click on htmlpage using silverlight**.

Comment: Can you use javascript ?

Comment: Can you list out "the lot of things"?

Comment: yes,we can use javascript...........

Comment: @101084_see , so did you try what I posted

Answer (score 1):

If you could use javascript here is your answer , but generally disabling the right click is not recommended.It will annoy some users.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var BM = 2; // button middle
        var BR = 3; // button right
        var msg = "MOUSE RIGHT CLICK IS NOT SUPPORTED ON THIS PAGE";

        function mouseDown(e) {
            try { if (event.button == BM || event.button == BR) { return false; } }
            catch (e) { if (e.which == BR) { return false; } }
        }
        document.oncontextmenu = function() {  return false; }
        document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
   </script>
```